# I 'shall/would' be highly obliged if you 'would'

Tags: modal-verbs

What the difference between two bold sentences is?

> I am sorry to state that I applied for a new telephone on 05.02.2016. Though more than two years have passed since the application, I have not received the new connection yet nor have I been informed at what stage my application for the connection is at present. Kindly let me know when I can expect the connection.
>
> **I shall be highly obliged if you take immediate steps in this regard.
>
>   I would be highly obliged if you would take immediate steps in this regard.**

My question is, are both the bold sentences correct In the above context? If yes, what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is certainly correct although the difference between "shall" and "will" has largely disappeared in modern American English. (But I have no knowledge of such nuances in Indian English.) The second sentence is what many Americans might well use instead. I am old fashioned enough that I would substitute "if you took" for "if you would take."

As a matter of personal style, the sentence appears very stilted and adds nothing substantive. If I were writing from scratch, I'd probably end with "Please let me know promptly when I can expect the connection," but place it in a separate paragraph. But that is my sense of style, not a comment on grammar or idiom.

Comment: I don't think "if you took" is old-fashioned. It reads better, given that, as you point out, the sentence looks stilted and unsubstantive.

Comment: 50 years ago, "took" would have been mandatory in the schools I went to, but today few use the old rules on sequence of tenses.